# how does wp.media javascript library work?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, uploads, media-library

I'm building a custom dashboard and I'd like to add a feature which allows a user to upload an image.

However, by calling `wp.media()` (with a title, button & multiple args) javascript throws an error `this.activateMode is not a function` - Shouldn't it pop-up the media view/modal?

> For clarifying, I'm calling `wp.media` in a button's click event callback
>   function. And yes, I load all the necessary styles/scripts by calling `wp_enqueue_media();` and I do see them in the page's source code. And wp.media is **not undefined**, so it is loaded.

WordPress has very limited dev docs overall, so I'm not sure what dependencies wp.media has/needs in order to work properly. I dove into the source code but couldn't find an answer. Seems like it should work properly by simply calling the `wp.media`

So.... What I'm missing?

Sure I could build my own modal for media CRUD actions by using WP REST API but it would be a time-consuming process.

Comment: Do you have a live version to take a look at? Have you checked that you're load order is correct?

Answer (score 2):

To solve " TypeError: this.activateMode is not a function " error, add lodash as an external in your webpack config file.

```
externals: {
   'lodash': 'lodash'
}
```

Comment: This needs more signal for `TypeError: this.activateMode is not a function`